# Taphandler to handle fillColor change of a shape path in QML (fill white while press and unfilled while release) via Taphandler

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to implement "press and release" on a Shape Item in QML.

**What I want to achieve is:**

1. The button will be unfilled (transparent)
2. while tap(press) on this
   shape, the fillColor will be #f3f3f3
3. while release, the fillColor
   will be transparent (unfilled)

Right now, I am using **TapHandler** to do this but the mechanism (See attached code below) is reversed, which is

1. The button will be filled with #f3f3f3
2. while tap(press) on this
   shape, the fillColor will be unfilled (transparent)
3. while release, the fillColor
   will be #f3f3f3

Here the code:

```
Item {
    id: customizedShapeButton
    x:123
    y:281
    width:233.458
    height:200.321
                       
    Shape {
        x: 2
        y: 2
        width:229.458
        height:196.321
    
        ShapePath {
            fillColor: taphandler1.pressed ?   "transparent" : "#f3f3f3"
    
            id: down_left
            fillRule: ShapePath.WindingFill
            PathSvg {
                path: "M223.6 128.871C231.411 121.061 231.411 108.397 223.6 100.587L128.871 5.85788C121.061 -1.95261 108.397 -1.95264 100.587 5.85785L5.85787 100.587C-1.95261 108.397 -1.95263 121.061 5.85786 128.871L44.0183 167.032C83.0707 206.084 146.387 206.084 185.44 167.031L223.6 128.871Z"
            }
            strokeWidth: 2
            strokeColor: "#f3f3f3"
            joinStyle: ShapePath.MiterJoin
        }
    
        TapHandler {
            id: taphandler1
    
            onTapped:{ console.log("tapped", eventPoint.event.device.name, "button", eventPoint.event.button, "@", eventPoint.scenePosition) }
        }
    }
}
```

Question:

So I tried to change `fillColor: taphandler1.pressed ?   "transparent" : "#f3f3f3"`
to `fillColor: taphandler1.pressed ?   "#f3f3f3" : "transparent"` However, this won't work and the button is unchanged while pressing. Can someone helps me figure out what I am doing wrong here? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you change `taphandler1.pressed` to `!!aphandler1.pressed` ? Or just rearrange the conditional `taphandler1.pressed ?  "#f3f3f3" :  "transparent" ` ?

Comment: I tried `fillColor: taphandler1.pressed ? "#f3f3f3" : "transparent"` and it worked as expected for me. Maybe you had a typo.